# Repetition of Same Function Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function

I wrote some codes to run a mcq test page but i think this is not the best codes.
I am a beginner and this is my first project. 
I used same function three times. 
How can i use single(or less) function(s) to run the whole page???

I want to create 50 quiz in one page and I tried for loop but it didn't work.

```
<table>
    <th>Q. No.</th>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
    <th>4</th>
    <th>5</th>

    <tr><td>01</td>
    <td><input type="radio" value="button1" id = "ans1" name="q1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" value="button3" name="q1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" value="button3" name="q1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" value="button3" name="q1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" value="button3" name="q1"></td>
    <td><p id="display1"></p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>02</td>
    <td><input type="radio" value="button2"name="q2" ></td>
    <td><input type="radio" value="button1" name="q2" id = "ans2"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" value="button1" name="q2"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" value="button1" name="q2"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" value="button1" name="q2"></td>
    <td><p id="display2"></p></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" onclick= "go1() , go2()" value="Submit">
<p id="demo1"></p>

<script>
function go1() {
    var x = document.getElementById("ans1");
    if (x.checked) {
        document.getElementById("display1").innerHTML = "Correct";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("display1").innerHTML = "wrong";
    }
}

function go2() {
    var y = document.getElementById("ans2");
    if (y.checked) {
        document.getElementById("display2").innerHTML = "Correct";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("display2").innerHTML = "wrong";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Define "didn't work", and how did you do it? Everything is the same except for a digit in a string. Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Answer (score 1):

pass your variables as parameters, and reuse the same function

```
function go(ans,display) {
var x = document.getElementById(ans);
    if (x.checked) {
        document.getElementById(display).innerHTML = "Correct";
    } else {
        document.getElementById(display).innerHTML = "wrong";
    }
}
```

Comment: Before you do this, please think about your data and it's structure.  Then think about how you intend to store the data and use it.  This will work for your example, but it isn't necessarily a great pattern.  There is opportunity for you to learn here if you think about the approach and your desired results.

Comment: Youre saying that using function parameters "isnt necessarily a great pattern"... what are you talking about? The question is "I used same function three times. How can i use single(or less) function(s) to run the whole page???"
Clearly the best way to reduce the amount of functions is to parametrize and no other solution to that problem, maybe you should rethink what a good pattern is.

Comment: I guess you skipped the part (the very beginning) where I urged them to think about their data and its structure and took my comment as a personal attack.  Yes your function will work.  Should they do this?  No.  You know what they should do?  Think about their data and its structure so they can use it to present the questions, check selected answers, and stray from identifying answers with hardcoded element ids.  So yeah, you fixed their exact example, but you didn't help a beginner with their approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for` loop, but first you should improve a few things in your HTML:

- `th` elements should be children of a `tr` element
- There is no need to use a `p` element inside a `td` element when that is all you have there. Just put text in the `td` directly.
- Don't use `id` values with an incremental number following. This is rarely a good idea. Instead use `class` without that sequence number. This is true for the `ans` and `display` values you have used.

In your JavaScript code:

- Iterate over the elements that have the above mentioned `class` values
- When placing text in your document dynamically, don't use `innerHTML`, but `textContent`, as the first is really for HTML encoded content, while the latter is for plain text (which is your case).
- You can use the ternary operator for deciding to put "Correct" or "Wrong"

Here is how it could look:

```js
function go() {
    var answers = document.querySelectorAll(".answer"); // select by class instead of id
    var displays = document.querySelectorAll(".display");
    answers.forEach((answer, i) => displays[i].textContent = answer.checked ? "Correct" : "Wrong");
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Q. No.</th>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
        <th>4</th>
        <th>5</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>01</td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="button1" name="q1" class="answer"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="button2" name="q1"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="button3" name="q1"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="button4" name="q1"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="button5" name="q1"></td>
        <td class="display"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>02</td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="button1" name="q2" ></td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="button2" name="q2" class="answer"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="button3" name="q2"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="button4" name="q2"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" value="button5" name="q2"></td>
        <td class="display"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" onclick="go()" value="Submit">
<p id="demo1"></p>
```

Now, be aware that the user of this page can inspect it and find out which answers are the correct ones before pressing the button. To avoid this, you should involve a server sided application, which would do the verification of submitted answers.